# Rectified images of same size as the initial ones

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, 3d-reconstruction

I want to rectify a stereo image pair in MATLAB. To rectify, I use the following call:

```
[J1,J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1,I2, cameraParamsStereo);
```

If I do this, then I only get the so called valid part of each image which is smaller than the initial image size. If I specify the argument `OutputView` as full, then I get rectified images which are larger than the original ones.

Is there a way to get rectified images that have the same size as the original ones?

Comment: I guess you can crop them

Comment: Yes, but I want to do it in a standard way. For example, get the same images I would get with OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in principle, but `rectifyStereoImages` does not support this.

Comment: Can I get them from the full view rectified images?

Comment: Not really. If you modify the rectified image, then `reconstructScene` may not work correctly.